# updating several records with one request in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

**Some quick context:**
I have a sql table and a eloquent model for *JobCards* and each *JobCard* has several *Operations* belonging to it. I have a table and model for *Operations*. The users of my application browse and edit *JobCards*, but when I say editing a *Jobcard* this can include editing *Operations* associated with a *JobCard*. I have a page where a user can edit the *Operations* for a certain *JobCard*, I submit the the data as an array of *Operations*.

I want a clean way to update the data for the *Operations* of a *JobCard*. There are 3 different actions I may or may not need to do:

1. Update an existing *Operation* with new data
2. Create a new *Operation*
3. Delete an *Operatation*

I tried dealing with the first 2 and things are getting messy already. I still need a way of deleting an *Operation* if it is not present in the array sent in the request.

Heres my code:

```
public function SaveOps(Request $a)
{
    $JobCardNum = $a -> get('JobCardNum');
    $Ops = $a -> get('Ops');

    foreach ($Ops as $Op) {

        $ExistingOp = JobCardOp::GetOp($JobCardNum, $Op['OpNum'])->first();
        if(count($ExistingOp)==0) {
            $NewOp = new JobCardOp;
            $NewOp -> JobCardNum = $JobCardNum;
            $NewOp -> fill($Op);
            $NewOp -> save(); 
            $this->UpdateNextOpStatus($JobCardNum, $NewOp);
        }
        else {
            $ExistingOp -> fill($Op);
            $ExistingOp -> save();

        }             
    }
```

Can anyone help with the deletion part and/or help make my code tidier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how your method should look like. Please note that, I added a new method `getCache($JobCardNum)` this method will get an array of operations per job card (assuming that your model is designed to be related this way) this method will go to the DB only once, to get all the Operations that you need for this `method call` instead of getting them one-by-one (in the `foreach` loop), this way you make sure that the expensive call to the DB is done only once, on the other hand you got your JobCard's operations in the form of an array ready to compare with the new ones (coming in the request), the return of this method will be in the form of (`key=>value` with the `key` being the operation number and the `value` being the operation object it self).

```
/**
 * This function will get you an array of current operations in the given job card
 * @param $JobCardNum
 * @return array
 */
public function getCache($JobCardNum)
{
    /**
     * asuming that the relation in your model is built that way. if not you should then
     * use JobCardOp::all(); (Not recommended because it will get a lot of unnecessary 
     * data )
     */
    $ExistingOps = JobCardOp::where('job_card_id', '=', $JobCardNum);

    $opCache = array();
    foreach ($ExistingOps as $Op) {
        $opCache[(string)$Op->OpNum] = $Op;
    }
    return $opCache;
}

public function SaveOps(Request $a)
{
    $strOpNum = (string)$Op['OpNum'];
    $JobCardNum = $a->get('JobCardNum');
    $Ops = $a->get('Ops');
    $opCache = $this->getCache($JobCardNum);
    foreach ($Ops as $Op) {
        if (!isset($opCache[$strOpNum])) {
            $NewOp = new JobCardOp;
            $NewOp->JobCardNum = $JobCardNum;
            $NewOp->fill($Op);
            $NewOp->save();
            $this->UpdateNextOpStatus($JobCardNum, $NewOp);
        } else {
            $ExistingOp = $opCache[$strOpNum];
            $ExistingOp->fill($Op);
            $ExistingOp->save();
        }
        unset($opCache[$strOpNum]);
    }

    /*
     * at this point any item in the $opCache array must be deleted because it was not 
     * matched in the previous for loop that looped through the requested operations :)
     */
    foreach ($opCache as $op) {
        $op->delete();
    }
}
```